# Dynamic pages using php

Tags: php, dynamic

I am trying to create dynamic pages on my website, but it fails.
When I try the code on `Xampp` it works perfect. There is another thing that I don't understand. 
It will catch the id, but not the title or anything with characters from the database.
When I try `$title = $_GET['title'];` it won't work. It works only with `$_GET['id'];`
Any help?

Here is the code:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include('inc/code.inc.php');

    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `star` ORDER BY `title`");
    while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch))
    {
        echo '<a href = "run.inc.php?id='. $output['id'] .'">'. $output['title'] .'</a><br />';
    }
?>
```

**run.inc.php**

```
<?php
include_once('inc/code.inc.php');

$newID = $_GET['id'];

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `star` WHERE `id` = $newID");

while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch))
{
    echo $output['title'] . '<br />' . $output['explain'];
}
?>
```

---

Here is the code that won't work:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include('inc/code.inc.php');

    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `star` ORDER BY `title`");
    while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch))
    {
        echo '<a href = "run.inc.php?title='. $output['title'] .'">'. $output['title'] .'</a><br />';
    }
?>
```

**run.inc.php**

```
<?php
include_once('inc/code.inc.php');

$newID = $_GET['title'];

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `star` WHERE `title` = $newID");

while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch))
{
    echo $output['title'] . '<br />' . $output['explain'];
}

?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are *deprecated* and *evil*. They're insecure, even if you escape your input. Support for them *will* be removed. Use **prepared statements** with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) instead. [Here's a simple tutorial](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to get started.

Comment: You don't have a URL parameter called `title`. That's what [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add title to your URL GET parameter please..Like you have added ID

```
<?php
include('inc/code.inc.php');

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `star` ORDER BY `title`");
while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch))
{
    echo '<a href = "run.inc.php?id='. $output['id'] .'"'.'?title='. $output['title'] .'</a><br />';
}
```

?>

Modify the url according to your needs please.

Comment: The title itself is alright, it shows. But the problem is on the run.inc.php where I get the title and it doesn't work.
For example this works:
run.inc.php?=10
This works, but if I try to change it to a title
run.inc.php?=php
It won't work.

Comment: The $_GET['title'] won't work. I tried changing everything needed and it still says:
Notice: Undefined index: titulli in C:\xampp\htdocs\prova.inc.php on line 4

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\prova.inc.php on line 8

Comment: Looks like you are using undefined variables with prova.inc.php. You can either set the variables where notice appears, or you can suppress the notice.  php.ini has error_reporting set to include E_NOTICE. You can suppress notices by setting error_reporting to E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE (not recommended), or verify that the variables exists before you attempt to access it.

Comment: Its very simple, I only add isset($variable). That is not the point

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing a string like `$_GET['title']` to the column, you need to escape it (as opposed to a numeric ID, which does not need to be escaped).

Try this for **run.inc.php**

```
$newID = $_GET['title'];

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `star` WHERE `title` = '$newID'");

while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch))
{
    echo $output['title'] . '<br />' . $output['explain'];
}

?>
```

Comment: I tried your method but it didn't work. I don't see where you escape your string. When adding another column which is integer, it works perfect. Only with strings it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You say that when you try it locally on xampp, it works fine- but it doesn't work on the server? Is the server database up-to-date ?

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to make it work first on xampp then i will find out alone what is the problem on the server because I have made a lot of mods there and its difficult to explain. For now I want to make it work locally.